# Spring Source Tool Help Needed

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-aop, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

i am applying AspectJ in spring source tool

do i need to configure load time or compile weaving in spring source tool

i will be very happy if any provide details of using AspectJ for applying Aspect on Spring Source Tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very advanced topic, way beyond the scope of a single StackOverflow question.

Basically:

- The simplest case is Spring AOP,
  where you don't use AspectJ at all,
  but create Java proxies from AspectJ
  annotations. This is also the least
  powerful option. Only a few pointcuts
  are supported, and the targets must
  be Spring Beans.
- The most powerful option is static
  AspectJ compilation, which you
  usually integrate in your build
  system (works fine with ant or
  maven). Your class files are actually
  changed to include the aspects. This
  is called compile-time weaving.
- Load-time weaving is somewhere
  inbetween. You want to advise code,
  but you don't want to change the
  class files, so you "advise the
  classloader" (this is not an adequate
  definition, but it gives you an
  idea). Loadtime-weaving is also
  usually your only choice if you want
  to add aspects to 3rd party library
  code.

You should read [AspectJ in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988053) by Ramnivas Laddad to understand all the subtle differences.

Either way, the settings you use in STS should reflect the settings you have in your build system. The section [7. Aspect Oriented Programming with Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html) from the Spring Reference is also very helpful.

Comment: thanks Sean...i am facing a strange ExceptionInInitializerError: NullPointerException for the beans which are advised by AspectJ..These beans are not intialized when context try to intialize..hopefully u will be able to address my query..i have added this problem in another link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5880552/using-ajc-compiler-with-spring-problem-aspectj)

Comment: @Vish yes, [I know](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5880552/342852). Post your aspect code there and I'll try to help you