# Using Ajc compiler with Spring problem AspectJ

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-aop

when i am trying to aspectj with spring using ajc compiler ,i  am getting  following errror.when i am removing aspectj then code is working fine
is there anything with the compile time weaving which is causing problem

```
caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:100)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:61)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:877)
... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.cdf.dfdxc.aspect.logging.LoggingAspect.logEntry(LoggingAspect.java:76)
at com.cdfc.fdged.uow.UdfdFactory.<clinit>(UOWfdy.java:1)
```

Spring bean file

```
<bean id="hibernateCertificateDao" class="com.Add.exasmple2.dao.HibernateCertificateDaoImpl" autowire="byType">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate">
        <ref bean="hibernateTemplate" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="AddCert" class="com.Add.exasmple2.uow.AddCertUOW" lazy-init="true" autowire="byType">
    <constructor-arg ref="oXMapper"></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="uOWFactoryBean" class="com.Add.exasmple2.uow.UOWFactory" />

<bean id="businessProcessManager" class="com.Add.exasmple2.infrastructure.BusinessProcessManager"></bean>

<bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate" >
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

classpath:/resources/hibernate-mappings

```
<bean id="exampleDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName">
        <value>com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver</value>
    </property>
    <property name="url">
        <value>jdbc:db2://20.15.29.108:50001/XC128086</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>db2dut$</value>
    </property>
    <property name="username">
        <value>db2dut</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="exampleHibernateProperties"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="properties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext
            </prop>
            <prop key="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider
            </prop>
            <prop key="c3p0.acquire_increment">3</prop>
            <prop key="c3p0.max_size">30</prop>
            <prop key="c3p0.min_size">3</prop>
            <prop key="c3p0.max_statements">0</prop>
            <prop key="c3p0.idle_test_period">0</prop>
            <prop key="c3p0.timeout">0</prop>
            <prop key="current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
            <prop key="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider</prop>
            <prop key="connection.autocommit">true</prop>
            <prop key="show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="format_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="use_sql_comments">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>



<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />


<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

logging aspect code

```
  @Pointcut("within(com.csc.exceed.uow.*)")
public void loggingAspect() {

}

// invoked before the method execution
@Before("loggingAspect()")
public void logEntry(JoinPoint joinPoint) {

    Class<? extends Object> clazz = joinPoint.getTarget().getClass();
    String name = joinPoint.getSignature().getName();

    if (ArrayUtils.isEmpty(joinPoint.getArgs())) {
        if (!(name.startsWith("get")) || (name.startsWith("set")))
            logger.log(LogLevel.INFO, clazz, null, BEFORE_STRING, name,
                    constructArgumentsString(clazz, joinPoint.getArgs()));
    } else {

        logger.log(LogLevel.INFO, clazz, null, BEFORE_WITH_PARAMS_STRING,
                name, constructArgumentsString(clazz, joinPoint.getArgs()));

    }
}
```

Comment: Please show your LoggingAspect code

Comment: i have added the code.if anything more is required please tell me

Comment: @Sean i have new   [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253118/spring-annotation-driver-transaction-with-aspectj-problem) regarding transaction and aspectj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult without knowing which line 76 is:

```
at com.cdf.dfdxc.aspect.logging.LoggingAspect.logEntry(LoggingAspect.java:76)
```

but you are using a very aggressive pointcut

```
@Pointcut("within(com.csc.exceed.uow.*)")
public void loggingAspect() {}
```

This matches all kinds of events, not only method executions, but also static and instance inititializers, field access etc. (see the **Primitive Pointcuts** overview in the [AspectJ Quick Reference](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/quick5.pdf)).

If any of these:

- returns `null` for `joinPoint.getTarget()`, this line will throw a NPE:

  ```
  Class<? extends Object> clazz = joinPoint.getTarget().getClass();
  ```
- returns `null` for `joinPoint.getSignature()`, this line will throw a NPE:

  ```
  String name = joinPoint.getSignature().getName();
  ```
- Also, here you are checking for null or empty args:

  ```
  if (ArrayUtils.isEmpty(joinPoint.getArgs())) {
      if (!(name.startsWith("get")) || (name.startsWith("set")))
          logger.log(LogLevel.INFO, clazz, null, BEFORE_STRING, name,
  ```

  but you are using the args nevertheless:

  ```
              constructArgumentsString(clazz, joinPoint.getArgs()));
  ```

  This might also throw a NPE, depending on the code in `constructArgumentsString()`

Check which of these happens on line 76, and you have your candidate for failure. But my first hint would be to replace your aggressive catch-all pointcut with an `execution` or `call` pointcut.

I would use a combined pointcut, defined in a modular way:

```
// you can easily reuse this
@Pointcut("within(com.csc.exceed.uow.*)")
public void myApp() {}

// and this
@Pointcut("execution(* *.*(..))")
public void methodExecution(){}

// but this is the pointcut you are actually matching
@Pointcut("myApp() && methodExecution()")
public void methodExecutionInMyApp(){}

@Before("methodExecutionInMyApp()")
public void logMethodExecutions(JoinPoint jp){
    // your code here
}
```

---

Here's how to make the class thingy NPE-safe:

```
Class<?> clazz = joinPoint.getTarget() !=null 
               ? joinPoint.getTarget().getClass() 
               : null;
```

Comment: sorry line 76 is Class<? extends Object> clazz = joinPoint.getTarget().getClass();..this was giving the error.actualy i was earlier using spring aop and there only joinpoints were are pointcuts and i used similar here,without fully understanding the reason.

Comment: @Vish exactly: Spring AOP only catches method executions, real AspectJ catches a lot more than that

Comment: @Sean thankfully i have been able to solve all issues using help given above ,i have only one problem, i am not able class object.this is always giving a null pointer exception....is there any way out here :)

Comment: @Sean thanks..i wish you were my teacher :)..anyways i will keep on troubling you when ever i face problem :) can you sugggest some good java book where i can master the fundamentals

Comment: @Vish a) you can look up my skype from my profile. You wouldn't be the first one to ask me questions every once in a while b) Books. For Java: Effective Java 2nd Ed by Joshua Bloch, for AspectJ and Spring AOP: AspectJ in Action 2nd Ed by Ramnivas Laddad, for Spring: Print out the PDF version of the Online Reference

Comment: @Sean i have added [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898911/spring-hibernate-transaction-logging) please give a look over it