# Spring hibernate Transaction Logging

Tags: java, spring, logging

how can we log spring Transaction mechanism. i am showing below example shown in [Spring Doc sec 10.5.2](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-decl-explained).if i want to logging upto this level how to do that

i am using Spring,Hibernate and Log4j.

```
<!-- the Spring container is starting up... -->
[AspectJInvocationContextExposingAdvisorAutoProxyCreator] - Creating implicit proxy
for bean 'fooService' with 0 common interceptors and 1 specific interceptors
<!-- the DefaultFooService is actually proxied -->
[JdkDynamicAopProxy] - Creating JDK dynamic proxy for [x.y.service.DefaultFooService]
<!-- ... the insertFoo(..) method is now being invoked on the proxy -->
[TransactionInterceptor] - Getting transaction for x.y.service.FooService.insertFoo
<!-- the transactional advice kicks in here... -->
[DataSourceTransactionManager] - Creating new transaction with name    [x.y.service.FooService.insertFoo]
[DataSourceTransactionManager] - Acquired Connection
[org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnection@a53de4] for JDBC transaction
<!-- the insertFoo(..) method from DefaultFooService throws an exception... -->
[RuleBasedTransactionAttribute] - Applying rules to determine whether transaction should
rollback on java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
[TransactionInterceptor] - Invoking rollback for transaction on x.y.service.FooService.insertFoo
due to throwable [java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException]

<!-- and the transaction is rolled back (by default, RuntimeException instances cause rollback) -->
[DataSourceTransactionManager] - Rolling back JDBC transaction on Connection
[org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnection@a53de4]
[DataSourceTransactionManager] - Releasing JDBC Connection after transaction
[DataSourceUtils] - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at x.y.service.DefaultFooService.insertFoo(DefaultFooService.java:14)
<!-- AOP infrastructure stack trace elements removed for clarity -->
at $Proxy0.insertFoo(Unknown Source)
```

Logging File..

```
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.rootLogger=info, stdout
log4j.category.org.springframework.transactions=DEBUG
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's [a section about Logging](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#d0e743) in the Spring Reference.

It shows how to configure different logging frameworks, among them [log4j](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#d0e826)

In your case the last line of the config would be:

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework.transaction=DEBUG
```

Comment: @Lucas thanks.. i have put mine log4j properties file above.can you suggest soem changes which can help me to log my j2ee application using Spring,hibernate

Comment: Do we need to some configuration for using log4j.category because this is not working in my application. :(

Comment: @Vish I copied that from the Spring docs but can't fin d it in the log4j docs. Changed to `logger` now

Comment: Also, in Spring 3.1 at least, the namespace is org.springframework.transaction, no (s).

Comment: is there any way to log the datasource or connection pool used by that transaction?

Comment: how to convert log4j to log4j2 version? log4j.logger.org.springframework.transaction=DEBUG. please help me with it

Answer (score 8):

If you're just willing to set the log level of spring transaction support, try adding the following logger to your log4j.xml :

```
<logger name="org.springframework.transaction">
        <level value="DEBUG" />
</logger>
```

Answer (score 0):

For hibernate 4 and above you can use:

```
org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl = DEBUB
```