# Spring Annotation driver Transaction with AspectJ problem

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, aspectj, spring-transactions

i am using AspectJ compile time weaving and spring 3.O. and Hibernate 3.0...AspectJ weaving is working fine for simple things like logging but this is not working correctly for Transaction

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"
    mode="aspectj" order="1" />
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Sprong-aspects jar is also present in the lib forlder but still transactional support is not working..

i am using like this

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public void invokeService() throws Exception {
    insertUpdatePolicy();
}
```

logging doesn,t specify any transactions..transactions are working fine with spring aop but not with aspectj when the class is not defined in the spring container

Comment: can you be more explicit about problem? any exceptions please paste it here.

Comment: @Adelave i am not getting exceptions but transaction is not invoked...ex transaction is not rolling back on exceptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found answer to this problem,

One thing we need to keep in mind that we need to place spring-aspects.jar  to my Aspect Path instead of java class path.otherwise weaving is not done  and transaction is not working.

Second thing i was missing following configuration in spring=bean config.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AnnotationTransactionAspect" factory-method="aspectOf">
<property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please post the actual code that is failing.

Enable logging. Check the logs to see if transactions are even being managed at all. If they are, then there is probably an issue with how you configured the transactions.

Comment: thanks fro showing interest but my logs doesnt show any transactions..that how i was able to figure out

Comment: Heh. Sorry for jumping the gun there. I've edited my response accordingly.